# How to retrieve the first argument when there is no Main()?

Tags: windows, c#, wpf

When the user drops a file icon on top of my application's icon, I am able to retrieve the filepath of the dropped file. It is contained in `args[0]`.

How can I retrieve that filepath when there is no `Main()`?

IOW: My latest app is not console-based.

Comment: How is  your app being started if it doesn't have a `Main()`?

Comment: How do you have a working C# program with no Main()?

Comment: @heavyd Apparently I'm not the only confused one. :)

Comment: You have to have a `Main()` method.  Why are you asking a programming question on Superuser?

Comment: "You have to have a Main()": That is only true for console-based applications. WPF and other types do not have a Main().

Comment: "Why are you asking a programming question on Superuser? " Because they kicked me out of StackOverflow. The mafia in charge over there cannot take criticism.

Comment: Just couldn't resist... For WPF the "Main" is hidden in auto-generated `obj\Debug\App.g.i.cs` or `obj\Release\App.g.i.cs` files. There is always a "Main" or another static entry point :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx) function to get the command line arguments at any time in your application.